# Does turning off an appliance (e.g. vacuum cleaner) at the power socket have any negative affect?

Tags: power

Does turning off an appliance (e.g. vacuum cleaner) at the power socket, rather than from the appliance itself; have any negative affect?

Comment: Are you talking about a power socket that has a built-in switch, or are you talking about pulling the plug from the socket while the appliance is on? I was assuming the former, but @DoxyLover seems to be assuming the latter.

Comment: I meant switching it off by using a switch at the power socket.

Comment: In this case, then it is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. you are causing arcing at the outlet which, over time, will damage the contacts in the outlet (as will as the prongs of the plug). The device's switch, on the other hand, should be designed to safely switch the current drawn by the device.

For a low-power device, such as a desk lamp, it doesn't matter that much but for a higher-draw device such as a vacuum, you should use the switch.

Comment: The switch at the socket ought to be rated for the full circuit current. OTOH, if your answer is about simply pulling the plug, I agree with you.